# After upgrading and moving to new server the wordpress admin dashboard is not displayed properly

Tags: magento, wordpress, wordpress-theming, fishpig

I have a blog set up in magento root directory.

`Update`I am using `Fishpig's Magento WP Integration`

The previous version of this was `3.8.1` now the version is `3.8.3`.

When I tried to login to my blog's admin, it asked me to upgrade the database.I upgraded the database on clicking the link provided.

Now my admin dashboard css files not loading properly. The buttons and menu placement is ok but css files are not loading.

When I see page source of Admin I get following

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.mymagentosite.com/blog/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&amp;dir=ltr&amp;load=dashicons,admin-bar,wp-admin,buttons,wp-auth-check&amp;ver=3.8.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='open-sans-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=3.8.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='thickbox-css'  href='http://www.mymagentosite.com/blog/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=20131201' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='colors-css'  href='http://www.mymagentosite.com/blog/wp-admin/css/colors.min.css?ver=3.8.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

In browser console I am getting

```
    "NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
 http://www.mymagento.com/blog/wp-admin/css/colors.min.css?ver=3.8.3"
```

But this file exists at the mentioned location and having `777` permission. [image]

what is the use of `wp-admin/load-styles.php?`

.htaccess file is having only one line in it `DirectoryIndex index.php`

Issue is in admin section only, the content is structured but no color is coming.

Please help.

**Temporary Solution:**  If I add this file http://www.mymagento.com/blog/wp-admin/css/colors.min.css statically. Problem solves

Comment: 777 is a bit scary.  Are you sure the directory is world-viewable?

Comment: @Jeremy Miller Even if I enter in browser url as http://www.mymagento.com//blog/wp-admin/css/ I get NetworkError: 404 Not Found

Comment: That's a hint to me that the directories don't have the right permissions, be they the owner or the read capabilities.

Comment: My mymagento.com/blog/wp-admin/css/ directory and all files insie are having the 777 permission

Comment: If this is happening from backend only? is your website front end displays properly?

Comment: @Bhavesh Front end is working well issue is with admin section only

Comment: did you do manual upgrade?

Comment: I had copied this blog directory from my client's live site long back.Recently I taken fresh from live site 2 days back.Then there was difference in versions of wordpress.

Comment: please check that load-styles.php file exists

Comment: This is usually caused because your WP URL's aren't setup correctly. If you include your real URL, I will be able to diagnose this straight away.

Comment: @BenTideswell but the issue is in admin, I can not provide the admin url

Comment: @Muk Consider this: Unless you've re-named the admin directory (wp-admin), providing your root WP path that's already publicly available is no different than providing your wp-admin path.  Ben didn't ask for your password (quite properly!)  It also means you're more likely to get an answer.